# How do you set application variables for a rebar dependency?

Tags: erlang, rebar, lager

I created a project using rebar called "mything". I added lager as a dependency. Now how do I configure lager? I tried adding a "lager" section to "env" in mything.app.src but it doesn't seem to get those settings. I guess I don't know where env settings for dependencies are supposed to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create `config_name.config` file which contains list of configurations for each appliaction you want to configure:

`[{mything, [...]},
{lager, [...]}].`

Then you can pass it to `erl` using option `-config config_name`. It's called system configuration and it overrides default environment properties from `.app` files. In releases it's usually named `sys.config`.

Resources for you: [Configuring an Application](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/applications.html#id74398) and [config](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/config.html).

Comment: So where do I put sys.config in a typical rebar setup? I tried it in the root and the src directory, but neither seemed to go into the release when I did "rebar compile generate".

Comment: @Matt create `rel` directory, get there and run`rebar create-node nodeid=release_name`. You should get typical files for release but it won't work yet. You need to edit `reltool.config` and change `lib_dirs` to `["../../"]`. `sys.config` is located in `files` directory. Now in rebar.config add `{sub_dirs, ["rel"]}`. Now `rebar generate` should work. You should read about [rebar](https://github.com/rebar/rebar/wiki), reltool and common practices.